# What imagery and symbolism would you associate with authority, knowledge and creativity?

Tags: identity, symbolism

Usually those three things tend not to go together and I'm struggling to come up with concepts that combine all three. Any ideas?

This will help me with research on an identity project I have coming up. Any contributions will be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a specific target audience? You mentioned in one of the comments the company is British; anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at classical forms. In architecture we studied how Greeko-roman architecture has been re-employed by empires and institutions (think government, banks etc) of all forms to conjure a sense of stability, security and authority.

Additionally the historical period was one where great minds pushed the boundaries of the arts and sciences. This is partly why universities and learning institutions also employ devices; names, statues, architecture, from the same period.

Comment: perhaps an injection into history may not be such a bad idea, they are a technology company, so maybe rendering some of these styles and combining it with techy style imagery may work well.

Answer (score 5):

Leonardo Da Vinci was the pinnacle of art, design and science of his time. Thinking along those lines, objects that are similar to being a nice combination of the three, assuming authority, could be the wonders of the world, especially the pyramids.

The pyramids represent an interesting idea since the three sides which coincides with your three criteria as well as representing an object that is a combination of art, sciences and authority.

Comment: Pyramid is a good theme! Definitely food for thought!

Answer (score 3):

The sphinx comes to mind when I think of these 3 together. Although, I also like the pyramid idea.

As far as people go, there are a number of excellent choices, but Thomas Jefferson is the first that jumps to mind as someone who clearly embodied all three of these traits.

I could potentially see an angel or similar celestial being as representative of these three, except that I don't believe it would apply to all angels.

That's all I have for the moment

Comment: the company is British so I'm not sure the Thomas Jefferson comparison would drive a message. I want to avoid celestial beings as I don't want to give a false "above the law" impression. The sphinx would work well though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Authority + Knowledge + Creativity = Einstein

Comment: Yes, but the Einstein estate is very protective of his images, so there is a potential landmine. Pretty much all of the calendars, postcards, t-shirts, etc. are all licensed.

Answer (score 0):

Authority and knowledge are symbolized with a book, plus a brush for creativity :)

[image]